# Azure Event Hub Storage Container Configuration for Azure Function with Input Binding

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-eventhub

When handling an Event Hub event with an input bound Azure Function, is it possible to change the Storage account configured for the Event Hub partition checkpointing?

Is it possible to do this with a Premium Storage account and in isolation (ie a different Storage account than the account selected for the Azure Function during set up)?

It seems that this is possible with the [EventProcessorHost](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.eventprocessorhost?view=azure-dotnet) but the Function doesn't seem to expose the EventProcessorHost configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I did a similar hack for some other propose.

First, stop your Azure function

Then, Create New Premium Storage account and Copy an existing blobs and container (All eventhub checkpointing files with the same folder structure).

Then change Azure function storage account connection string to new premium storage account.

Then start your Azure function.

Comment: I can't get this to work on my end.  I can't get the contents of the source blob container copied into the premium blob container - neither through azcopy or storage explorer.  If I only update the azure function storage account connection string, the function never starts up again as it complains of incompatibility.  This is the reason I hoped to configure the event hub client storage account separate from the azure function storage account.

Comment: I created folder manually under the container and copied blob